# Parsing a tree - Collecting data for each node, recursively (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, tree

I have a tree structure as follows which is rendered using jsTree:

```
Root
    Child 1
        Child 1 - 1
        Child 2 - 2
    Child 2
Root2
    Child 1
```

The tree is created dynamically by the user from the UI using a form and button clicks for adding nodes and attributes for each node. These attributes are collected using a form when the user clicks on a particular node. I am storing the node information in a list with node name and it's parent as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li data-node="Root 1" data-parent = ''>[Form to add attributes]</li>
    <li data-node="Child 1" data-parent="Root 1">[Form to add attributes]</li>
    <li data-node="Child 2" data-parent="Root 1">[Form to add attributes]</li>
```

... and so on.

I need to collect that data, in the following JSON format:

```
Root1: {
    formdata: {...}
    children: {
        Child 1: {
            formdata: {...}
            children: {
                Child 1 - 1: {
                    formdata: {...}
                }
                Child 1 - 2: {
                    formdata: {...}
                }
            }
        }
        Child 2: {
            formdata: {...}
            children: {
                Child 1 - 1: {
                    formdata: {...}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and so on.

It could be N levels deep. I am only able to visualise collection going down one branch. If I dig into `Root 1 > Child 1 > Child 1 - 1`, I am not able to figure out how to come back to the parent, while maintaining the collected data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first two data structures are unclear... Which language is that? If you have them in JSON, could you provide the literal JSON, or if it is a JavaScript object, could you provide the literal object syntax? You refer to the DOM. Can you provide some HTML + JS that demonstrates what you are doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traversing a tree javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978539/traversing-a-tree-javascript)

Comment: All of this is JavaScript, I have simply represented it without a language.

Comment: We need to have the HTML and JS, otherwise it will be guessing what you are working with. I vote to close this as too broad.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Checking it out!

Comment: @trincot Why do you need HTML and JS to understand the problem? Just think of it as parsing a tree using JavaScript, like Anurag did.

Comment: Parsing what? There is nothing in your question to parse. Only a *sketch* of some structure. Code needs real data to work, not just an idea. Now anyone that goes ahead and answers with some particular implementation choice will risk to get a reaction from you: "ok, but my HTML looks actually quite different, so this solution wont work for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit to your question, it looks like that extra data are available as `form` inputs, or maybe the form is just the tool to end up with additional `data-` attributes on the `li` elements.

#### 1. With FormData

I'll first assume these data are accessible via the standard `FormData` API. So for instance, if a form has `<input name="country">`, its value will be available under the `country` key.

Here is how you could build a tree object from scanning the DOM:

```js
function collectTree(ul) {
    // Create the nodes & identify the root
    let nodes = {};
    let root = null;
    for (let li of ul.children) {
        // Extract form data using the FormData API
        let formdata = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(li.querySelector("form")).entries());
        nodes[li.dataset.node] = { formdata };
        if (!li.dataset.parent) root = nodes[li.dataset.node];
    }
    // Populate the children arrays
    for (let li of ul.children) {
        if (!li.dataset.parent) continue;
        let p = nodes[li.dataset.parent];
        if (!p.children) p.children = {};
        p.children[li.dataset.node] = nodes[li.dataset.node];
    }
    return root;
}

const root = collectTree(document.querySelector("ul"));

console.log(root);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-node="Root 1" data-parent="">
        <form>
            <input name="address" value="Abbey Road 1">
            <input name="country" value="UK">
        </form>
    </li>
    <li data-node="Child 1" data-parent="Root 1">
        <form>
            <input name="address" value="Champs-Elysées 9">
            <input name="country" value="FR">
        </form>
    </li>
    <li data-node="Child 1 1" data-parent="Child 1">
        <form>
            <input name="address" value="Downing Street 10">
            <input name="country" value="UK">
        </form>
    </li>
    <li data-node="Child 2" data-parent="Root 1">
        <form>
            <input name="address" value="Wall Street 1">
            <input name="country" value="US">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### 2. With additional `data-` attributes

If the extra data is not present in the form, but become additional `data-` attributes to the `li` elements (that was not clear to me), then it is similar:

```js
function collectTree(ul) {
    // Create the nodes & identify the root
    let nodes = {};
    let root = null;
    for (let li of ul.children) {
        // Extract form data using the FormData API
        ({ node, parent, ...formdata} = li.dataset);
        nodes[node] = { formdata };
        if (!parent) root = nodes[node];
    }
    // Populate the children arrays
    for (let li of ul.children) {
        if (!li.dataset.parent) continue;
        let p = nodes[li.dataset.parent];
        if (!p.children) p.children = {};
        p.children[li.dataset.node] = nodes[li.dataset.node];
    }
    return root;
}

const root = collectTree(document.querySelector("ul"));

console.log(root);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-node="Root 1" data-parent="" data-address="Abbey Road 1" data-country="UK"></li>
    <li data-node="Child 1" data-parent="Root 1" data-address="Champs-Elysées 9" data-country="FR"></li>
    <li data-node="Child 1 1" data-parent="Child 1" data-address="Downing Street 10" data-country="UK"></li>
    <li data-node="Child 2" data-parent="Root 1" data-address="Wall Street 1" data-country="US"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, although for one top level root, which is exactly the scenario in my case. I was trying for multiple top level roots, just in case I need to modify it later. My form data isn't exactly like this, it's a complex form with multiple conditions, however I was able to adapt it accordingly. Thank you. I was thinking in terms of recursion, however I was going down a branch, and wasn't able to figure out how to get back to the parent, to continue traversing.